# netsh acl setting (need alternative method - registry settings?)

Tags: powershell, registry, inno-setup, acl, netsh

I am using inno-setup to install a program that needs to unblock port 4326 on Win7 (permit acl access) so that GET operations can be done over HTTP to port 4326.

I have a powershell script that an admin can run to unblock the port. But this does not work as an inno-setup [run] command (because the local machine usually disables scripts from running). (i.e powershell.exe -nowait & script.ps1)

Is there some registry keys in the target machine that I can set that will unblock the port? That I can do pretty easily in inno-setup since the setup.exe runs as an admin. I guess a self-contained EXE could do the same thing.

Here is the script that I would like to replace with just setting the registry settings in HKLM.

```
set-alias netsh c:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe
$PORT = 4326
$domain = $Env:userdomain
$name = $Env:username
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";

netsh http delete urlacl url=http://*:$PORT/
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:$PORT/ user=$domain\$name
```

Comment: if that's all your script, you can just [run] directly the netsh.exe from your installer.

Comment: That's a good idea. But then how do I get ahold of the username/domain from inside of inno-setup? I am running the setup.exe with temporary elevated privilidges (admin). I see a constant in inno-setup for username: {username}

    The name of the user who is running Setup or Uninstall program (as returned by the GetUserName function).

Comment: I do not want to open this up for all users, just the one running setup.

Comment: If that's your case, write a simple bat script (you really don't need powershell for that simple script) and run it with the [runasoriginaluser flag](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection). If you really want to do this only for the current user, be aware of the limitations of the runasoriginaluser when the user selects "run as administrator" from the shell to launch your setup.

Comment: I am going to say running netsh.exe is the answer. But I am having one issue with it. I don't know if this is the proper etiquette but I am posting it as a new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024881/running-netsh-exe-as-a-post-install-in-inno-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [running netsh.exe as a post-install in inno-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024881/running-netsh-exe-as-a-post-install-in-inno-setup) for a continuation of this question. But I basically, jachguate's answer of running netsh.exe as a post install seems the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find firewall rules in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\`

suggestion :
maybe you can just export this key as .reg and import it on the other station .

Comment: It's a bad idea to mess with registry entries directly unless you have no alternative -- Microsoft make no guarantees to keep this working in future versions of Windows, unlike APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `netsh`, use the WinApi [HttpSetServiceConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364503.aspx) instead.  You can call this (and its related functions) directly from Inno's `[Code]` (specifically, in `CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`), given the correct prototype declaration.  See the [Using DLLs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm) topic in the help file.