# running netsh.exe as a post-install in inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup, acl, netsh

In the following script, I run netsh.exe to enable http on a TCP port (GET request). But even though the setup log is saying the exit code is 0, and the parameters are correct. I am not seeing the port enabled. Any ideas?

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Netsh"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Draper Laboratory"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.draper.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{112CF442-ACA5-4799-BC72-72C98F90CED1}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
CreateAppDir=no
OutputDir=C:\Users\ysg4206\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
ChangesEnvironment=True
SetupLogging=True

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: "http delete urlacl url=http://*:4326/"; WorkingDir: "{sys}"; Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser; Description: "Remove Web Port 4326"
Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: "http add urlacl url=http://*:4326/ user={%USERDOMAIN}\{%USERNAME}"; WorkingDir: "{sys}"; Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser; Description: "Add Web Port 4326"
```

and here is the log:

```
2012-12-24 14:02:43.123   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-05:00)
2012-12-24 14:02:43.123   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.2 (a)
2012-12-24 14:02:43.123   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\ysg4206\Desktop\setup.exe
2012-12-24 14:02:43.123   Setup command line: /SL5="$4A0C72,54272,54272,C:\Users\ysg4206\Desktop\setup.exe" /SPAWNWND=$EF1420 /NOTIFYWND=$3540C26 /log="setup.log"
2012-12-24 14:02:43.124   Windows version: 6.1.7601 SP1  (NT platform: Yes)
2012-12-24 14:02:43.124   64-bit Windows: Yes
2012-12-24 14:02:43.124   Processor architecture: x64
2012-12-24 14:02:43.124   User privileges: Administrative
2012-12-24 14:02:43.124   64-bit install mode: No
2012-12-24 14:02:43.128   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ysg4206\AppData\Local\Temp\is-JCDBN.tmp
2012-12-24 14:02:45.492   Starting the installation process.
2012-12-24 14:02:45.495   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Windows
2012-12-24 14:02:45.496   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Windows\unins000.dat
2012-12-24 14:02:45.500   -- File entry --
2012-12-24 14:02:45.501   Dest filename: C:\Windows\unins000.exe
2012-12-24 14:02:45.504   Time stamp of our file: 2012-12-24 14:02:42.959
2012-12-24 14:02:45.504   Dest file exists.
2012-12-24 14:02:45.504   Time stamp of existing file: 2012-12-24 14:02:22.794
2012-12-24 14:02:45.505   Version of our file: 51.52.0.0
2012-12-24 14:02:45.506   Version of existing file: 51.52.0.0
2012-12-24 14:02:45.506   Installing the file.
2012-12-24 14:02:45.511   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2012-12-24 14:02:45.608   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2012-12-24 14:02:45.669   Installation process succeeded.
2012-12-24 14:02:45.832   Need to restart Windows? No
2012-12-24 14:02:46.661   -- Run entry --
2012-12-24 14:02:46.661   Run as: Current user
2012-12-24 14:02:46.661   Type: Exec
2012-12-24 14:02:46.661   Filename: C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe
2012-12-24 14:02:46.661   Parameters: http delete urlacl url=http://*:4326/
2012-12-24 14:02:46.831   Process exit code: 0
2012-12-24 14:02:46.831   -- Run entry --
2012-12-24 14:02:46.831   Run as: Current user
2012-12-24 14:02:46.831   Type: Exec
2012-12-24 14:02:46.831   Filename: C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe
2012-12-24 14:02:46.831   Parameters: http add urlacl url=http://*:4326/ user=CSDL-SERVICES\ysg4206
2012-12-24 14:02:46.951   Process exit code: 0
2012-12-24 14:02:46.953   Deinitializing Setup.
2012-12-24 14:02:46.959   Log closed.
```

Comment: As I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959440/netsh-acl-setting-need-alternative-method-registry-settings?lq=1), you should be using the API instead of trying to call netsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further testing, indicates it is working. But I would love to have a way of pausing the cmd.exe box which flashes up, shows some text and then exits. Can't really see what the message is.

Comment: You can hide the flashing cmd box by adding the runhidden flag to that line.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but it wasn't working for me when I tried to run netsh.exe directly as in the original question and answer.

My solution was to run it as a powershell command.  In my case, I did not use the postinstall flag.

```
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
Parameters: "-NonInteractive -Command netsh http add urlacl url={#MyURL} user='{#MyServiceUser}'"; \
Description: "Add URL registration"; StatusMsg: "Adding URL registration..."; \
Flags: runhidden; Components: MyComponentA;
```